# PrintForm cropping the right side of the form

Tags: c#, .net, printing, printform

Alright, so when I issue the

```
this.printform1.print();
```

the related code

```
            this.printForm1.DocumentName = "document";
              this.printForm1.Form = this;
               this.printForm1.PrintAction=System.Drawing.Printing.PrintAction.PrintToPreview;
                 this.printForm1.PrinterSettings =((System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings)(resources.GetObject("printForm1.PrinterSettings")));
                   this.printForm1.PrintFileName = null;
```

command the printpreview and the printed document shows up,its trimmed from the right side with a great margine, I can't seem to find the reason.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Pkease, provide your code and more details

Comment: one line of code is not going to get you much help in regards to `Details and information` that we would need to see as well as have

Comment: The PrintForm class was only ever meant to be a substitute for the equivalent VB6 feature.  Which didn't allow controlling the size and position of the image either.  Just use the form's DrawToBitmap() method to create a bitmap that you can position and resize as you want with the PrintDocument class.